# margin-top property in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

Why does margin-top value not work in IE?

Works fine in FF and Safari. Here's the [link](http://wms-clients.com/psc/andrew_test/index.html)

Thanks

Comment: What version of IE. There is considerable variation in CSS support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Collapsing Margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

Comment: bloody haslayout, grumble grumble

Answer (score 0):

I see your #papertop is empty. Try adding some &nbsp; inside to see if that does the trick.

**Edit: forget it; this doesn't work.**

Comment: Should I try negative margins?

Comment: If possible, avoid negative margins as much as you can; they are really nasty.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick workaround this will achive the same thing.

```
#papertop {
background:transparent url(images/paper_top.png) no-repeat scroll right bottom;
height:250px;
position:relative;
z-index:300;
}
```

Comment: That worked great for IE, thanks! But now FF is showing too much margin! This is a headache!